# MongoDB historical data query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

I'm recording historical data for different items and I've perhaps wrongly decided to store the data in one collection per item as an array of objects ie:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("616d4e1c1e7edf6e9bcdd668"),
    "collectibleId" : "bc50774d-b923-4a5c-8e5d-f25608e1e80e",
    "1634553373797" : {
        "storePrice" : "39.99",
    },
    "1634554743600" : {
        "storePrice" : "39.99",
    },
    "1634558354739" : {
        "storePrice" : "39.99",
    },
    ...
}
```

I'd like to know given the above data (key is a unix timestamp) how I could go about fetching all of the data between date A and date B.

Thanks,

Comment: Using dynamic data as the key sounds like a bad idea. Why not something like `historical: [ { date: "1634...", storePrice: "39.99" }, { date: "...", storePrice: "..." }, {...} ]`? It would be easier to query.

Comment: I agree with Matt - try to avoid data points as field names.  Unless using the wildcard index, you cannot index these fields because the field names will never be known at design time and will exceed the limit of 64 indexes per collection (not to mention poor performance).  The pattern Matt is suggesting is the attribute pattern.  See here for details - https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-attribute-pattern.